# What does it mean for a smooth atlas to not be properly contained in any larger smooth atlas?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, he defines a smooth atlas as maximal if it is not properly contained in any larger smooth atlas. What does this mean? Any atlas covers the manifold so it can't be the domain that he's referring to. In the following example, also given by Lee but in a different context, which one is maximal?

> $\mathscr{A}_1 = \{(\mathbb{R}^n, Id_{\mathbb{R}^n})\}$
>
> $\mathscr{A}_2 = \{(B_1(x), Id_{B_1(x)}) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither $\mathscr{A}_1$ nor $\mathscr{A}_2$ is maximal, since they are both properly contained in $\mathscr{A}_1 \cup \mathscr{A}_2$, and that union isn't maximal either. On the other hand, any smooth atlas is contained in a unique maximal atlas---just add in all of the compatible smooth charts.

Comment: What is the union of $\mathscr{A}_1 \cup \mathscr{A}_2$? Isn't it true that $\{\mathbb{R}^n\} = \{(B_1(x): x \in \mathbb{R}^n)\}$?

Comment: It's just the set-theoretic union. And the right-hand side of the equality doesn't make sense. If you mean that the right-hand side should be $\{B_1(x) : x \in \Bbb R^n\}$, then no, the equality is false: The left-hand side is a set containing a single element, and the right-hand side is a set containing infinitely many elements.

Comment: But isn't $\mathbb{R}^n = \cup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} B_1(x)$? Isn't that what you mean by the set-theoretic union?

Comment: The atlases $\mathscr{A}_i$ are sets who elements are charts $(U, \phi)$, hence so is their union. Your latter equation is true, but it's comparing union of the sets $U$ themselves\.

Answer (score 0):

The word "larger" here is redundant with "contained in" and contributes no additional meaning.  "Contained in" means literally one atlas is a subset of the other, as a set of charts.  So, an atlas $A$ is maximal if there does not exist any other atlas $B$ such that $A\subset B$.

Comment: What does it mean for it to be a subset of another? The union of all the charts produces the manifold, so what's the difference?

Comment: It very very literally means that one is a subset of the other.  An atlas is a set of charts.  So two atlases satisfy $A\subseteq B$ if every chart that is in $A$ is also in $B$.